# assignment switch case c ++

Tags: c++, loops, switch-statement

Requirements

1. VULTURE IS V, OWL IS O, EAGLE IS E...
2. A `for` loop to input the data each bird watcher has collected.
3. inside the `for` loop, a `do ... while` loop to input and process the data collected by one bird watcher.
4. inside the `do ... while` loop a `switch` statement is used to calculate the number of eggs for each type of bird. the default option, which does nothing, is used when an `x` is entered.
5. the `do ... while` loop is exited when an X is entered for the type of bird.
6. The totals part is fine as per code below

ok, now my problem is I can't seem to get through my switch case. It prompts me for the first watcher's info, when I enter it, it never moves over to the next watcher.

The input data given is

```
3
E2 O1 V2 E1 O3 X0
V2 V1 O1 E3 O2 E1 X0
V2 E1 X
```

And here is the code that I got so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

int totNrVultureEggs, totNrEagleEggs, totNrOwlEggs, nrEggs,
   nrVultureEggs, nrEagleEggs, nrOwlEggs, nrBirdWatchers, nrEggsEntered;

char bird;

// initialize grand totals for number of eggs for each type of bird
cout << "How many bird watchers took part in the study?";
cin >> nrBirdWatchers;

// loop over number of bird watchers
for (int i = 0; i < nrBirdWatchers ;i++ )
{
// initialize totals for number of eggs for each type of bird
// this bird watcher saw
nrVultureEggs = 0;
nrEagleEggs = 0;
nrOwlEggs = 0;
cout << "\nEnter data for bird watcher " << i + 1 << ":" << endl;

//loop over bird watchers
do{

    cin >>  bird >> nrEggs;
    switch (bird)
    {
        case 'E':
        case 'e':
            nrEagleEggs = nrEagleEggs + nrEggs;

        case 'O':
        case 'o':
            nrOwlEggs = nrOwlEggs + nrEggs;

        case 'V':
        case 'v':
            nrVultureEggs = nrVultureEggs + nrEggs;

        default :
        nrBirdWatchers++;
        break;

    }

    }while (i < nrBirdWatchers )
;
cout << "Bird watcher " << i + 1 << " saw " << nrVultureEggs;
cout << " vulture eggs, " << nrEagleEggs << " eagle eggs and ";
cout << nrOwlEggs << " owl eggs " << endl;
// increment grand totals for eggs
}

// display results
cout << "\nTotal number of vulture eggs: " << totNrVultureEggs;
cout << "\nTotal number of eagle eggs: " << totNrEagleEggs;
cout << "\nTotal number of owl eggs: " << totNrOwlEggs;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You've forgotten `break;` in each of your `case:` statements. meaning that as soon as ANY case is matched, ALL of the code in the rest of the cases BELOW that point is executed.

Comment: i added it but it still does not want to work...                                    case 'E':
            case 'e':
                nrEagleEggs = nrEagleEggs + nrEggs;
            break;
            case 'O':
            case 'o':
                nrOwlEggs = nrOwlEggs + nrEggs;
            break;
            case 'V':
            case 'v':
                nrVultureEggs = nrVultureEggs + nrEggs;
            break;
            default :
            nrBirdWatchers++;
            break;

Comment: so what output do you see?

Comment: [LINK]http://postimg.org/image/660ci1kv7/

Comment: and then the program stops responding and no further input is granted

Comment: @user2164151: Please copy-and-paste the output *as text*. A screenshot is less useful -- especially on a site that shows potentially NSFW images.

Comment: How many bird watchers took part in the study?3  
  
Enter data for bird watcher 1:  
e3  
x  
x

Comment: there are multiple problems wrong with this code, in the for loop you initialize eggs to 0 each time the loop is run and at no point do you update the totNr.. Eggs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote the whole program, now it works, but take care of the input:
because of the type of the input, you have to give ALWAYS a couple of `char-int`, or you will have a bad time xD [The problem is in the buffer].

So the input would be:

```
3
E2 O1 V2 E1 O3 X0
V2 V1 O1 E3 O2 E1 X0
V2 E1 X0
```

The source below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    bool done;
    char birdType;
    int eagleEggs, owlEggs, vultureEggs;
    int totEagleEggs, totOwlEggs, totVultureEggs;
    int eggsTemp, eggsIn, birdWatchers;

    cout << "How many bird watchers took part in the study?";
    cin >> birdWatchers;

    totEagleEggs = totOwlEggs = totVultureEggs = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < birdWatchers ;i++ ){
        eagleEggs = owlEggs = vultureEggs = 0;
        done = false;

        cout << endl;
        cout << "Enter data for bird-watcher n. " << (i + 1) << ":" << endl;
        do{
            cin >>  birdType >> eggsTemp;
            switch (birdType)
            {
                case 'E':
                case 'e':
                eagleEggs += eggsTemp;
                totEagleEggs += eagleEggs;
                break;

            case 'O':
              case 'o':
                owlEggs += eggsTemp;
                totOwlEggs += owlEggs;
            break;

            case 'V':
            case 'v':
                vultureEggs += eggsTemp;
                totVultureEggs += vultureEggs;
            break;

            default:
                done = true;
            }
        }while (!done);

        cout << "The bird-watcher n. " << (i + 1) << " saw " << vultureEggs;
        cout << " vulture eggs, " << eagleEggs << " eagle eggs and ";
        cout << owlEggs << " owl eggs." << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Total number of vulture eggs: " << totVultureEggs << endl;
    cout << "Total number of eagle eggs: " << totEagleEggs << endl;
    cout << "Total number of owl eggs: " << totOwlEggs << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this solved my issue with my switch case... thank you so very much..., but cant seem to get my final results to show after the program has looped

Comment: I'm sorry, I forget a pause in the end of the program [I start command prompt programs from cmd, not with double click =P].
Actually the program printa also the final results, but it exits before you can read them.

You have just to add `system ("PAUSE");` before the command `return 0;`.

[I edited the answer]

Comment: OK I have added the Pause but for some reason it does not pass beyond the end of the FOR loop just as the totals are supposed to display.

Comment: I ma using codeblocks and compiling directly from codeblocks, dont know it that makes any difference??

Comment: nevermind, works perfectly, instead of using x at the last person, use x0 and then it prints totals and all is well, thank you very much for all your trouble @IngrossoD

Answer (score 1):

You need a break after each switch case. Also, you need a boolean variable 'done' to tell you when a single birdwatcher is done.

```
 bool done = false; //Flag to note when a birdwatcher is done
 do {
     string data;
     cin >>  data;
     bird = data[0];
     nrEggs = data[1]-0;
     switch (bird)
     {
     case 'E':
     case 'e':
         nrEagleEggs = nrEagleEggs + nrEggs;
         break; //was missing before

     case 'O':
     case 'o':
         nrOwlEggs = nrOwlEggs + nrEggs;
         break; //was missing before

     case 'V':
     case 'v':
         nrVultureEggs = nrVultureEggs + nrEggs;
         break; //was missing before

     default :
         done = true; //changed: No more birds to report
         break;

     }
 }while (!done) //Check if there are birds to report
```

Comment: i added it but still does not give desired result

Comment: STILL iT DOES EXACTLY THE SAME

Comment: [LINK]postimg.org/image/660ci1kv7

Comment: Is the input like this E2 O1 V2 E1 O3 X0
V2 V1 O1 E3 O2 E1 X0
V2 E1 X or like E 2 O 1 V 2...

Comment: In the second case, your program should work. When you do cin >> bird >> nFlags it expects the bird and nFlags to be space seperated which in your case is not true. You probably need to do a complicated parsing mechanism in that case.

Comment: it is E2 without spaces and the O1 as specified in my question

Comment: See edited answer. Note that my solution will only work if nrEggs is single digit. For example, E2 should work but E21 will be a problem. For multiple digits you have to string manipulation and convert a string to int, instead of char to int which I am doing in the solution by data[1] - 0.